# Makefile .c + .as with ncurses

Tags: c, linux, assembly, makefile

I have some problems with compiling my program to use ncurses. Im new in creating makefiles so:

Here's my makefile:

```
test_reservation: reservation.o service.o
    gcc -g -m32 service.o reservation.o -o test_reservation 
service.o: service.c
    gcc -g -m32 -c -o service.o service.c -std=c99 -lncurses
reservation.o: reservation.s
    as -gdbb --32 -o reservation.o reservation.s
```

I've already installed and included  in my c file

When I'm trying to make it:

```
gcc -g -m32 service.o reservation.o -o test_reseration
service.o: In function `main':
/home/xxx/reservationService/service.c:23: undefined reference to `initscr'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:2: recipe for target 'test_reservation' failed
make: *** [test_reservation] Error 1
```

What's wrong with this makefile? How should I compile it?

Comment: You need to add the `-lncurses` to the linking command (the first rule) not the compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a better Makefile skeleton for you:

```
PKGS    := ncursesw
CC      := gcc
CFLAGS  := -Wall -m32 -O2 -std=c99 $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(PKGS))
LDFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --libs $(PKGS))
AS      := as
ASFLAGS := -gdbb --32
PROGS   := test-reservation

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(PROGS)

clean:
    $(RM) *.o $(PROGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

%.o: %.s
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) $^ -o $@

test-reservation: reservation.o service.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

If you copy-paste the above, remember to run `sed -e 's|^  *|\t|' -i Makefile` to fix the indentation.

Most Linux distributions use `pkg-config` to keep track of the options needed to compile a specific library. You just need to add the packages you need to the `PKGS` variable, separated by spaces. `ncursesw` is the version of ncurses that supports wide characters (you'll want Unicode character output). The `$(shell pkg-config ... $(PKGS))` idiom uses the `pkg-config` shell command to pull in the correct flags (`--cflags`) and library files (`--libs`).

If you use `<math.h>`, you'll want to prepend `-lm` to `LDFLAGS`; i.e., `LDFLAGS := -lm $(shell pkg-config --libs $(PKGS))`.

If you compile several binaries in that directory, just add the final binary name to `PROGS`, and add the new rule, e.g.

```
foo-bin: foo.o bar.o baz.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

the rule action does not change, only the target and the prerequisites change.

With the `all: $(PROGS)` rule, you only need to run `make` to compile all binaries named in `PROGS`. If you modify say `service.c`, then both `service.o` and `test-reservation` will be recompiled. Run `make clean all` to remove any compiled files, then recompile them all.